# Interesting Trigonometry Identity

Tags: trigonometry

### Prelude

While studying trigonometry, I came across this very interesting problem. It wasn't very difficult to solve, however it's result was quite interesting. I have given the solution below. Try to solve it yourself before looking.

---

### Problem

The diagram below shows three equal squares, with angels $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ as marked. Prove that $ \alpha + \beta = \gamma $.

[image: diagram]

---

### Hint

If you are not in the midst of a trigonometry course, chances are you will need to see this hint, as it is an uncommon identity.

*Hover below to see a hint.*

> $ \arctan a + \arctan b = \arctan{\frac{a + b}{1 - ab}} $

This identity was solved earlier in the book I found this problem in (see **Postscript**). Try to prove this identity for yourself, too!

---

### Postscript

This problem came from the textbook: "Trigonometry" by I. M. Gelfand.

---

Comment: I know this this not the place to ask, but how do you hide your hint? I've been trying to figure that out for ages.

Comment: @Hamed -- I just learned how to do so 2 minutes before I posted this question. `:)` [You can find out here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9454/multiline-hidden-text).

Comment: @Blue -- Actually, it's not really a duplicate. The OP of the question you linked asked for a non-trig solution. However, anything goes for this one.

Comment: @SirJony: People may have seen it [mentioned by Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5evLoL0xwg) a couple of years ago. As I note in my [Trigonography entry](http://trigonography.com/2016/01/10/three-squares-puzzle/), the puzzle was featured by Martin Gardner in 1996, and dates back to at least 1971.

Comment: @Blue -- Oh, that's interesting. I'd never heard of this problem before reading Gelfand's book. Thanks for the history and other references! However, does this still make my question a duplicate, if it hasn't been asked (trig-style) on Math SE before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Proof

---

**Step 1:** Gather information from diagram.

- $ \alpha = \arctan \frac{1}{3} $
- $ \beta = \arctan \frac{1}{2} $
- $ \gamma = \arctan 1 $

---

**Step 2:** Add $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and simplify.

$ \alpha + \beta = \arctan \frac{1}{3} + \arctan \frac{1}{2} = $

*...Now, using an identity (see hint given in the question)...*

$ = \arctan {\frac{\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2}}{1 - \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{2}}}
= \arctan {\frac{\frac{5}{6}}{1 - \frac{1}{6}}}
= \arctan {\frac{\frac{5}{6}}{\frac{5}{6}}}
= \arctan 1
= \gamma $

---

### Answer

Indeed,  $$ \alpha + \beta = \gamma $$